# Calendar With a taxonomy field as filter

Tags: datetime

[image]I have created a calendar showing Events in different cities.The City names are taken as Taxonomy and are displayed as a filter.On selecting a Particular city the Calendar shows all the events of that particular city in that month.I want the number of events in that particular city in the filter next to the city name.On clicking the City name in filter it should display the event details under it.
Eg.If Atlanta have 4 events and Chicago have 1 event in July it should be displayed as

- Atlanta(4)
- Chicago(1)

  for that particular month.
  On clicking the City the display is like-
- Atlanta

  - Event1
  - Event2
  - Event3
  - Event4

How to get this Functionality please help.

Comment: is your form exposed or do you want these cities in checkboxes also?

Comment: Cities Are expose form.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/494026 this might help you in some way

Comment: I don't have much time tonight to write the code but i can tell you the way how to do it as i did my it yesterday..

you have to alter the exposed form which gives you $form['tid'], then you have to loop throught it and write a query to get the number of nodes and append that count with $form['tid'].. .= '('.$count.')';

Comment: or if you can wait till monday i will give you the code also

Comment: or second option is that you can use search api module with facets that will give you exactly what you want

Comment: This will show event count for a particular month right?

Comment: It depends on your views fiteration

Comment: Any body can help me in the above asked question??

Comment: probably you are going to the wrong track i can say because you want to display taxonomy terms with event count attached and on click of that you want you want to display all the event with all 4 event details say..

For that you can do this first of all make a view to display all taxonomy terms with count as suggested then provide the link with using rewrite output that links the above view . so you have to make another view for displaying the taxonomy terms only. In your view in contextual filter, filter by taxonomy terms from the url.

Comment: I tried but for getting the collabsible division I finally ended up in block template overriding.Thanks.